# Can't install GStreamer to anaconda(linux. Debian)

Tags: python, linux, debian, anaconda, python-3.6

Well, I have a problem with installing GStreamer 1.0 to anaconda.
I use this command to install it to a *testenv*:
`conda install -c conda-forge -n testenv pygobject`.
 
But when I try to get a *Gst* namespace, using `import gi; gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')`, it throws an exception

```
/home/user/anaconda3/envs/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 130, in require_version
    raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace)
    ValueError: Namespace Gst not available
```

I tried to reinstall anaconda, pygobject and others.
I don't want to make a link in environment from /usr/bin/gi, because it can cause errors.

---

[Link to a Russian mirror](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/780782/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-gstreamer-%D0%B2-anaconda-3-linux-debian)